# Error when unit testing cloud function: no document found to update

Tags: firebase, unit-testing

I am following the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) for unit testing. I created a simple cloud function that is triggered when a firestore document is created. It turns the value in that document to uppercase. I tried the function by creating a document and it worked as expected.

I use jest for the test. When I run the test I get the following error:

```
NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/test/testId

  10 |   return admin.firestore().doc(`test/` + snap.id)
> 11 |               .update({ input: input });
     |                ^
  12 | });
```

I added a console.log to my function to see what data was passed by the unit-test. It passes the right data (meaning the right document id and the right value for "input".

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. It's a simple function and a simple test. I don't understand how the function could receive the right data but not found the document, or how the document is not created in firestore when the test is run.

The function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const makeUpperCase = functions.firestore
.document('test/{id}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const data = snap.data();
  const input = data.input.toUpperCase();
  console.log('new data: ' + input + ', id: ' + snap.id);
  return admin.firestore().doc('test/' + snap.id)
              .update({ input: input });
});
```

index.ts:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

export { makeUpperCase } from './makeUpperCase';
```

the test (basicTest.test.ts):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions-test';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'jest';

const testEnv = functions({
  databaseURL: "https://mydb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myproject",
}, './service-account.json');

testEnv.mockConfig({});

import { makeUpperCase } from '../src/index';

describe('basicTest', () => {
  let wrapped: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapped = testEnv.wrap(makeUpperCase);
  });

  test('converts input to upper case', async () => {
    const path = 'test/testId';
    const data = { input: 'a simple test' };
    const snap = await testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, path);
    await wrapped(snap);
    const after = await admin.firestore().doc(path).get();
    expect(after.data()!.input).toBe('A SIMPLE TEST');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your use of the `import` syntax. Unlike `require`, the `import` instructions are performed asynchronously **before** the script that is importing them is executed.

```js
import * as module1 from 'module1';

console.log(module1);

import * as module2 from 'module2';

console.log(module1);
```

is effectively (not exactly) the same as

```js
const module1 = require('module1');
const module2 = require('module2');

console.log(module1);
console.log(module2);
```

Because of this quirk, in your current code, `admin.firestore()` is incorrectly pointing at your **live** Firestore database and `test.firestore` is pointing at your **test** Firestore database. This is why the document doesn't exist, because it exists on your test database, but not your live one.

This is why the [documentation you linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) uses `require` statements, and not the `import` syntax.

```js
// this is fine, as long as you don't call admin.initializeApp() before overriding the config and service account as part of test's initializer below
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'jest';

// Override the configuration for tests
const test = require("firebase-functions-test")({
  databaseURL: "https://mydb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myproject",
}, './service-account.json');

test.mockConfig({});

// AFTER mocking the configuration, load the original code
const { makeUpperCase } = require('../src/index');

describe('basicTest', () => {
  let wrapped: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapped = test.wrap(makeUpperCase);
  });

  test('converts input to upper case', async () => {
    const path = 'test/testId';
    const data = { input: 'a simple test' };
    const snap = await test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, path);
    await wrapped(snap);
    const after = await admin.firestore().doc(path).get();
    expect(after.data()!.input).toBe('A SIMPLE TEST');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately it didn't work, I'm still getting the same error.